# Validating/checking for values after dashes in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I really need your help,

I’d like to make a function so as to validate (return valid or invalid) that the following string below (represented by the var x) has values after each of the 7 dashes

```
var x = 4-D-5240-P43-120-08A2-8123-0000 (valid)
```

Some examples below of strings where x is invalid)

```
var x = 4--5220--120-08C2-8072- (invalid)
var x = 4--5217-P41-120--8072- (invalid) 
var x = --5217-P41---8072- (invalid)
```

I've tried the following, but errors when there is no value:

```
function test() {

var str1 = "4-D-5240-P43-120-08A2-8123-0000" //works
    str1 = str.split('-')

var str = "4--5240-P43--08A2-8123-0000" //error here <--
    str = str.split('-')

if (str.length < 8) { alert('validation failed') }
else { alert('validation passed!') }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is for specific questions about particular programming issues, not for just saying what you want done and then expecting someone to provide you with the answer. You have to make some sort of effort.

Comment: Look into regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered Regex?

```js
const
pattern = /(([\d\w]+)-([\d\w]+)-([\d\w]+)-([\d\w]+)-([\d\w]+)-([\d\w]+)-([\d\w]+)-([\d\w]+))/,

strs = ["4-D-5240-P43-120-08A2-8123-0000", "4--5217-P41-120--8072-", "--5217-P41---8072-", "4--5220--120-08C2-8072-"];

strs.forEach((str) => {

   console.log(`${str} is valid: ${ pattern.test(str) }`);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this using regex.

```js
   var regex1 = /[0-9|a-z][-][0-9|a-z]/g;
   var str = "4--5220--120-08C2-8072-";
   var str1 = "4-D-5240-P43-120-08A2-8123-0000"


  if(str.match(regex1).length== 4)  {
  alert("match");
  }
  else
  {
  alert("no match");
  }
  if(str1.match(regex1).length== 4)  {
  alert("match");
  }
  else
  {
  alert("no match");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So for 1st declared the code and data-target "-"

```
var id= "100-2-8-8-8-8-8ssss80-0";
var arr = id.split("-");
```

1st step of checking if code is valid or no. Of we will have less or more  than 7 dashes output will be  invalid otherwise function will run anouther function to check if we have dashes in right place.

```
function countDash(){
 if (arr.length ==8){
        result();
    }
    else{
        alert("invalid");
    }
}
```

After we split our function we need to check if every value of array have a value. If dash will be 1st,last or multicharacter we will get empty value.

```
function check(value){
return value.length<1;
}
```

Now we use function that we declarete before to check every value of array.  So if array will be empty we will have output invalid otherwise code will be valid

```
function result(){
    if(arr.some(check)){
        alert("invalid");
    }
    else{
        alert("valid");
    }
}
```

Finally we need to run 1st function.

```
window.onload= countDash ;
```

I hope I explain you well how it goes. If there is something else to do just let me know.